# What is electrostatic energy that is found outside a capacitor?

Tags: electromagnetism

Electrostatic energy is given the following two definitions:

$$W_e = \frac{1}{2} \int_v \rho_v V\, dV = \frac{1}{2}\int_{R^3} \vec{D} \cdot \vec{E}\, dV $$

Using the field quantities, you must integrate all over space. Whereas with the other definition you only integrate where $\rho_v$ charge density exits. However, in many problems (let us say you have a capacitor made from a dielectric) people divide the energy stored in the capacitor and out of the capacitor (second definition integrating within the capacitor vs the rest of space). What exactly does the "energy stored outside" the dielectric mean?